# Firebase Email verification with SMS like Code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

It is possible to use email verification with firebase but instead of sending a link they have to click, it should send a code like a sms verification code and i have to check in my ios app (swift based) if they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email verification ensures that the user has access to the email address they claim. Setting an email address to verified by sending a text message is not the same, as you can't know from the receipt of the text message that they have access to the email address.

But as A. Welch commented, you can verify that the user has access to a specific phone number by using Firebase's phone number authentication as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

If neither of those does precisely what you want, you can also roll your own. Send a text message or email with whatever information you want, and [use the Firebase Admin SDK to update the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).